# Returning the index of the previous matching entry for each row in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: sample]

I need to create a dynamic array which contains an index to the previous instance of an entry in a column for each entry in the column. Also ignoring empty entries.

```
    =LET(s,SEQUENCE(ROWS($E$4#)),BYROW(s,LAMBDA(r,LET(b,INDEX($E$4#,r),IF(b<>"",XMATCH(1,(s<r)*($E$4#=b),,-1),"")))))
```

This works but feels cumbersome.

I thought there might be a simpler method I missed.

If I pass an array into XMATCH I can match to that but that array will simply return the index to the last instance of each value.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be:

```cpp
=MAP(E3#,LAMBDA(_,LET(c,OFFSET(_,1,),IF(c="","",XMATCH(c,E3:_,,-1)-1))))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have an E3# only an E4#. Also it searches E3 which could cause an issue. But I modified it to:-    =MAP($E4#,LAMBDA(_,LET(r,$E4:_,IFS(_="","",ROWS(r)=1,NA(),TRUE,(XMATCH(_,DROP(r,-1),,-1))))))

Answer (score 1):

Another option - without volatile `Offset`

```vb
=LET(data,A4:A23,
firstRow,ROW(INDEX(data,1)),
MAP(data,LAMBDA(r,
                IF(r<>"",XMATCH(r,TAKE(data,ROW(r)-firstRow),0,-1),""))
         )
)
```

To avoid errors:

```vb
=LET(data,A4:A23,
firstRow,ROW(INDEX(data,1)),
IFERROR(MAP(data,LAMBDA(r,
                 IF(r<>"",XMATCH(r,TAKE(data,ROW(r)-firstRow),0,-1),""))
         ),"")
)
```

It resizes the array for `XMATCH` based on the current row by using `TAKE` function

Comment: I made an amendment to check for first row to avoid a calc error if so.

Comment: You could also add an `IFERROR`